# Releasing a resource from super class that has been used in overridden method

Tags: java

Let's say I have an abstract class Shape with a draw() method. And two classes, Circle and Triangle that extend the Shape class overriding super class' draw method. I use a Pen resource to draw either of the shapes. And I want to release (close or nullify) the Pen resource immediately after calling the sub classdraw() method, but it has to be done in the Parent class. How can we achieve this?

This is only a sample code that I am trying to create the above scenario (may not exactly reproduce the above)

```
class Pen {

    Pen() {
        System.out.println("Pen initialized");
    }

    public void drawShape(Shape s) {
        if(s instanceof Circle) {
            System.out.println("Drawn Circle");
        } else if(s instanceof Triangle) {
            System.out.println("Drawn Triangle");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Released pen resource");
    }
}

abstract class Shape {
    Pen pen;
    Shape() {
        pen = new Pen();
        System.out.println("Shape constructor");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Draw Shape");
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    Circle() {
        System.out.println("Circle constructor");
    }

    public void draw() {
        super.pen.drawShape(this);
    }
}

class Triangle extends Shape {
    Triangle() {
        System.out.println("Triangle constructor");
    }

    public void draw() {
        super.pen.drawShape(this);
    }
}

public class ShapeTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Shape s  = new Triangle();
        s.draw();
    }
}
```

In the above code, how can I call the close() method of Pen class after executing the subclass' draw method and release the Pen resource in the super class itself?

Comment: If you're only talking objects, then there's little to be gained here - there's no guarantee if or when Java's garbage collector will run.  If you're talking about a system resource, like a file or a socket or something along those lines, then there's an entirely different conversation to be had.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
abstract class Shape {
  Pen pen;
  Shape() {
    pen = new Pen();
    System.out.println("Shape constructor");
  }

  protected void draw() {
    System.out.println("Draw Shape");
  }

  public void doDraw() {
    draw();
    pen.close();
  }
}
```

Call `doDraw()` instead of `draw()` directly. I changed the visibility of `draw` to `protected`

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I would apply the Template Method Pattern. It would look like this:

```
abstract class Shape {
    Pen pen;
    Shape() {
        pen = new Pen();
        System.out.println("Shape constructor");
    }

    abstract void drawImpl();    

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Draw Shape");

        drawImpl();
        pen.close();
    }
}
```

Now, instead of overriding `draw()`, you can override `drawImpl()`, as shown in this example `Circle` class:

```
class Circle extends Shape {
    Circle() {
        System.out.println("Circle constructor");
    }

    void drawImpl() {
        super.pen.drawShape(this);
    }
}
```

The Template Method Pattern can be applied anywhere an algorithm can be decomposed into distinct operations, each of which can potentially be overridden independently. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) has a good explanation, diagrams and example code.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked after using the Template method pattern, as Ken Wayne VanderLinde has suggested

```
   class Pen {
    Pen() {
        System.out.println("Using Pen");
    }

    public void draw(Shape s) {
        if(s instanceof Circle) {
            System.out.println("Draw Circle");
        } else if(s instanceof Triangle) {
            System.out.println("Draw Triangle");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Pen resource closed");
    }
}

abstract class Shape {
    Pen pen;
    Shape() {
        pen = new Pen();
    }
    abstract public void draw();

    public void drawShape() {
        draw();
        pen.close();
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {

    public void draw() {
        super.pen.draw(this);
    }

}

class Triangle extends Shape {

    public void draw() {
        super.pen.draw(this);
    }

}


public class TemplateMethodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = new Triangle();
        s.drawShape();
    }
}
```

The following is the output

```
Using Pen
Draw Triangle
Pen resource closed
```